# Blossom Algorithm

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory

I have noticed that in the blossom algorithm, we need to find the blossom while finding the augmenting path. What will happen if I just know there is a blossom in a graph and the contracted graph has an augmenting path. Will the original graph not have that augmenting path or will be same?

Edit to make it clear:- 
This is problem 8 from Chapter 10 from Combinatorial Optimization: Algorithms and Complexity Christos H. Papadimitriou

Theorem : Suppose that, while searching for an augmenting path, from a node u of a graph G with respect to a matching M, we discover a blossom b. Then there is an augmenting path from u in G with respect to M iff there is one from u (vb if u is the basis of b) in G/b with respect to M/b.

Show by an example that if G = (V;E) is a graph, M a matching of G, and b a blossom (a circuit with 2m + 1 edges, m of which are in M), then the following may fail to be true : There is an augmenting path in G with respect to M iff there is one in G/b with respect to M/b. Compare with above theorem.

Answer (score 1):

What does "*just know*" mean?  It is hardly something that would be part of an algorithm.

But the important thing to note is that each iteration of the algorithm starts with a valid (possibly null) solution and finds either a better solution or a simpler form of the graph.

So if at any time, you have some magic way of producing a better solution, independent of the algorithm, there's no reason you couldn't simply use it, and then continue using the algorithm on that improved intermediate solution.

Comment: This is how it is mentioned in the question. Instead of finding the blossom we already know of one. I have updated the original question